# Q-chem equivalent solvent settings for Gaussian NMR ab inito methods

Tags: computational-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy, density-functional-theory

I'm attempting to use Q-Chem 5.0 to replicate CHESHIRE-esque  http://cheshirenmr.info/ ab initio calculations of chemical shift values. Unfortunately Gaussian seems to be the predominant tool in this space, and translating from Gaussian16 to Q-Chem is quite a challenge with respect to the solvent model. Currently, just to debug, I am

1. Performing geometry optimization in Gaussian `B3LYP/6-31+G(d,p)
   (gas phase)`
2. Using those geometries in both Gaussian `mPW1PW91/6-311+G(2d,p)
   (giao, scrf)` and Q-Chem. For Gaussian, the solvent setting is
   `scrf=(solvent=chloroform,smd)`.

For step #2, both agree in the gas phase (to within 3 digits!) but in solvent I get very different answers (Q-Chem is off by ~3ppm in 13C vs Gaussian's 2.1ppm for my dataset.) I think this suggests that I am using the Q-Chem solvent model wrong, which is considerably more complex than what Gaussian seems to expose.

For a start, I have been using:

```
$rem
BASIS  6-311G**
METHOD  mPW1PW91
JOBTYPE  NMR
SOLVENT_METHOD  smd
$end


$smx
solvent  trichloromethane
$end
```

in my solvent settings for Q-chem, with the above results. Can anyone recommend a set of [Q-chem solvent settings](http://www.q-chem.com/qchem-website/manual/qchem50_manual/sect-solvent.html) that might yield more accurate chemical shift values and approximate whatever Gaussian's solvent model is doing? I'm also totally open to a different set of best-practices for Q-chem.

Comment: There's a Q-Chem specific forum at [iOpenShell](http://iopenshell.usc.edu/forum/) - either they, or Q-Chem technical support may have better advice. If so, please post an answer so others can find it in the future!